# Convert EulerAngle + yaw of the object to Vector

Tags: math, vector, rotational-matrices, euler-angles

So I have the point "D", the yaw rotation "Y" of the complete object and the EulerAngle of the arm sitting on the shoulder. Now I want to find out the vector "V" and at the end the point "P". I also know the length of the arm. It's around 0.7. I have spend lots of hours with a friend of mine trying and changing values. He is much better then me with rotation matrices etc but he gave up. So I searched in the web but did not find a suiting answer. Can someone help me/us?

[image: View Picture]

Answer (score 0):

Start with the vector `V` in your coordinate system (I presume (0, -1, 0)).

Now rotate it by the rotation matrix for rotating around axis X by the angle at which the arm is lifted (assuming angle=0 means the arm points down).

Finally, rotate the vector around the Y axis with the proper angle coming from the base rotation of your stick figure.

This gives you the vector V in world coordinates. Add it to the point D if you want to get P.

Comment: That seems to work but what about the rotation around the z and y axis? At the moment the rotation around the z axis is very low but it's there. So i just rotate it around the z axis with the z rotation of the eulerangle? The y rotation should matter. But I'm curious would I use rotateAroundY(baseRotation + yEulerAngle)?

Comment: EDIT: As soon as I change the x eulerangle of the arm to like 90 for example the location does not match the hand of the arm anymore. The output point is somewhere behind the object. I tested it with the x angle 0 and it does indeed mean that the arm points down. And at the angle of 0 it perfectly works but as soon as I change it it does somehow get more and more inaccurate.

Comment: Code:  `public Vector3f angleToVector(EulerAngle angle, double yaw) { 
        
  Vector3f vec = new Vector3f(0, -1, 0);  
               
  Matrix3x3f m = Matrix3x3f.IDENTITY.deepClone(); 
             
     m.multiply(Matrix3x3f.getRotationMatrixX(angle.getX()));  
     m.multiply(Matrix3x3f.getRotationMatrixY(Math.toRadians(yaw)));  
     //m.multiply(Matrix3x3f.getRotationMatrixZ(angle.getZ()));  
     
     return m.multiply(vec);  
 }
`

Comment: @Jalau: I don't know what framework you're using, but you may need to reverse the order in which you multiply these matrices.

Comment: I'm using a custom made one by my friend: http://pastebin.com/mrGDYEmJ  The Vector3f constructor looks as follows:  ' public Vector3f(float x, float y, float z) {
  super();
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;
 }
'

Comment: @Jalau: Try multiplying the matrices in reverse order.

Comment: So first around the Z Axis then Y Axis and then around the x axis?

Comment: As of now it works great! Thanks! I will contact you if I notice something off.

Comment: But I neded to invert the yaw. EDIT: If I change the Z rotation it still is somehow very off somewhere other. And how do I add the Y rotation if I already use the yaw and rotate that around the y axis but also have the y rotation of the arm. How can I add that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jalau Instead of "hiding" code in comments, please place them in your question so that those who would like to help you can have an easier time looking at them.